How to use await with GDExtension-wrapped external library functions?
I am looking at wrapping functionality from an external C++ library with GDExtension for use with Godot 4. Many of these functions have an appreciable runtime before they return the values of interest, so I was anticipating using coroutines with the wrapped functions to avoid having the display inadvertently "hang" while the processing is happening.
How would I do this? What are best practices regarding wrapping a long-running external function with GDExtension and then using GDScript's await to call them? Is there a standard pattern here?
